# 中身がクラスオブジェクトの Array をクラスオブジェクトのママで差集合

Tags: ruby

下記のような中身がクラスオブジェクトの２つの配列があり、その差集合を取りたいです

```
foo_people
#=> [#<Person:0x007fd36402cee0> @name="ichiro", #<Person:0x007fd36484c940> @name="jiro", #<Person:0x007fd364aac118> @name="saburo"]
bar_people
#=> [#<Person:0x007fd364a6f3a8> @name="ichiro", #<Person:0x007fd364a36170> @name="jiro"]
```

イメージとしては下記のような形ですが、object_id が異なるために差分を取得できなくて困っています。

```
foo_people - bar_people
#=> [#<Person:0x007fd364aac118> @name="saburo"]
```

Answer (score 3):

はじめまして。`Array#-`は、アイテムの比較に`Object#eql?`を使うので
`Person`クラスに、`eql?`メソッドを定義して同一性を保証する必要があります。
また、`eql?`メソッドを定義した場合は`hash`メソッドも定義する必要があるので、そちらも忘れずに定義して下さい。

今回の例だと、`Person`クラスに（`@name`というメンバーしかないという前提ですが）、

```
def eql? (other)
    other.name == @name
end

def hash
    @name.hash
end
```

を追記してあげれば目的通り、オブジェクトIDが異なっても内容が同じなら配列の差分が作成されます。

`@name`以外にもメンバーを持っているのであれば、hashはもう少し賢く定義して下さい。（メンバーを全て文字列にして結合した文字列のhash値を返すとか・・・）